# How to avoid interupted CSS animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

If you hover your mouse under the text but inside the div, the animation will be interrupted mid way and makes this glitchy "animation" where the element keeps on switching between from being animating and not animated.

```css
@keyframes hover {
  0% {bottom: 0px; border-radius: 0%;}
  100% {bottom: 100px; border-radius: 10%;}
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#i {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 100, 0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#i:hover {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: hover 0.5s ease;
    bottom: 100px;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="i"><strong>Hover</strong></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a problem when the user goes past a button too quickly, so how do I fix this?

Comment: Why use an animation here? It sounds more like a transition. And for the :hover issue, a trick is to use a transparent pseudo element that doesn't move.

Comment: Aren't transitions and animations the same thing?

Comment: No they're not. An animation works from keyframes, while a transition works from state. For instance here you only animate when moving up but not when moving down. A transition would do both, and even be able to handle in-between transitions (e.g if you stop hovering before the element reaches its final position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `#i` moving up (position changes) and your hovering position is still the same which does not have `#i`. Therefore, it's applied `#i` styles (not `#i:hover` styles).

You can add a container element for `#i` that will help you reserve the container space for hovering behavior.

```css
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 100px;
    border-radius: 10%;
  }
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container #i {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 100, 0);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container:hover #i {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: hover 0.5s ease;
  bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="i"><strong>Hover</strong></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Just one side note, `animation` does support a full animation cycle if the animation is completed. If you try to interrupt it while animating, CSS does not help you to complete it (a glitch will happen).

In that case, you can use `transition` instead of `animation`

```
transition: 0.5s ease;
```

If you want to have a complex animation with `keyframes`, you can consider having Javascript to handle it, you can check [this document](https://javascript.info/js-animation) out.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Keyframes here at all, think simple...
You can write the needed transformations in the `:hover #i` section.

Now your animation is very smooth and you dont have the glitch, that when you move the cursor away while the animation is playing, the block doesnt just fall down.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container #i {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 100, 0);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container:hover #i {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="i"><strong>Hover</strong></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```